# How to make my C# checkbox remember value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Here is my timer enabled/disabled code:

```
{
if (checkboxConsoleStats.Checked == true)
{
frmMain.frmObj.consoleStatTimer.Enabled = true;
}
else if (!checkboxConsoleStats.Checked == false)
{
frmMain.frmObj.consoleStatTimer.Enabled = false;
}
```

I want to make the form remember the 'Checked' value after termination of the form and the application, sorry this is vague, I am in a rush. Thanks.

Comment: No time to leave a full answer, but you need to listen to the `CheckBox.CheckedChanged` event and save the value to persistent storage - probably a file, a database, or in the application settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to store the value after full termination of the app - you'll have to use a persistent storage that the app can access on init.

The easiest would be to use a flat file (just store a flag), but if you believe you will have more values that you'll need to remember - consider using XML/JSON file that you parse upon init and write to upon termination.

If you have more dynamic data (that needs to be written and read while the app is running) - you should consider using a DB. For a small app you can use an embedded DB such as SQLITE. Easy to use and needs no installation for the end-user.

Comment: This worked, I stored the value of CheckState in the Application Settings, it doesn't save after the application is completely terminated, but I have realized that I do not need that feature anyway. Thanks.